# Reduce template parameters tightly linked to each other

Tags: c++, templates, traits

I have the following code:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
void Func(void); // signature
```

Simple template function with 4 template parameters. The usage of this is currently like this:

```
Func<Foo1, Foo1Helper, Foo1Client, Foo1Server>();
Func<Foo2, Foo2Helper, Foo2Client, Foo2Server>();
Func<Foo3, Foo3Helper, Foo3Client, Foo3Server>();
```

Now in the usage examples, `Foo1Helper, Foo1Client, Foo1Server, Foo2Helper, Foo2Client, Foo2Server, Foo3Helper, Foo3Client, Foo3Server` are generated classes based on the `Foo1, Foo2, Foo3` classes.

What i want to achieve is to simplify the `Func` templated function so that it can be called like this:

```
Func<Foo1>();
```

without needing so specify also the generated classes since the name of the classes is bounded to the original class.

Do you have any suggestions on how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what does *generated classes* mean, but you can provide a metafunction for them:

```
// declare metafunctions
template <typename T>
struct Helper;

template <typename T>
struct Client;

template <typename T>
struct Server;

// provide implementations
template <>
struct Helper<Foo1>
{ using type = Foo1Helper; };

template <>
struct Client<Foo1>
{ using type = Foo1Client; };

template <>
struct Server<Foo1>
{ using type = Foo1Server; };

// the same for Foo2, Foo3, etc
```

and then use them in `Func`:

```
template <typename T>
void Func()
{
    using THelper = typename Helper<T>::type;
    using TClient = typename Client<T>::type;
    using TServer = typename Server<T>::type;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a macro.  The syntax is a little different but you could have something like

```
#define PARAMS(name) name, name##Helper, name##Client, name##Server
```

And then you would use it like

```
Func<PARAMS(Foo1)>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could group `Foo` related class like that:

```
struct FooProfile {
    using T = Foo1;
    using Helper = Foo1Helper;
    using Client = Foo1Client;
    using Server = Foo1Server;
};
```

And pass it like that:

```
Func<FooProfile>();
```

The function implementation would look like that:

```
template<typename Profile>
void Func() {
    using T = typename Profile::T;
    using Helper = typename Profile::Helper;
    using Client = typename Profile::Client;
    using Server = typename Profile::Server;

    // stuff
}
```